# How to create pagination in laravel when my custom query like How to use this result in predesign webpage

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```php
// blog list page
    public function blogs(Request $request)
    {
        $perPage = 10;
        $offset = 0;
        $page = $request->has("page")?$request->page:1;

        if($page > 1){
            $offset = ($page - 1)*$perPage;
        }
        $blogs = Blog::where(['status' => 1])->offset($offset)->limit($perPage)->get();
        return view('frontend.blog', ['blogs' => $blogs]);
    }
```

Here my query to get data in with perpage and page number. How to use it frontend.

Comment: Laravel has built in support for pagination - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this code for get data with pagination with per_page

use this code into in your model

```
public function getPerPage()
{
    return request('per_page');
}
```

and for get data models with pagination

```
Blog::where(['status' => 1])->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does it for you: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#basic-usage

You only need to be sure to send the `page` query string argument in your url.

So your code should look like this:

```
public function blogs(Request $request)
    {
        $perPage = 10;
        $blogs = Blog::where(['status' => 1])->paginate($perPage);
        return view('frontend.blog', ['blogs' => $blogs]);
    }
```